# search using apache lucene

Tags: lucene

I want to use lucene to make searching on my database table fast.
The table query is `select x,y,z from  tablexyz`.The searchable field is x.It has 2 million rows.I want to use it in a web application and show the data on a  search page.Has anyone used Lucene to store entire table in a text file?

Comment: what do you mean by storing entire table in a text file?

Comment: If the table has 2 million rows.Then all rows will be stored in text file to enable searching for apache lucene.Check:  http://sphinxsearch.com and  http://lucene.apache.org/ for details.

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Whether anyone has used Lucene to store a table in a text file?

Comment: my database query is working very slow for search across 2 million rows.I want to improve performance of search using the apache lucene.hence i am trying to find out how much would apache lucene based search help.

Comment: And what exactly is your query? The one you wrote in the question has no condition on it, so it's not searching for anything.

Comment: The search is this way select x,y,z from tablexyz where fieldx like 'country%' .I want to find out which is better lucene or ehcache.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is what you are looking for.

To get started:

- first read the [tutorial to understand the basics](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html),
- then have a look at [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) which would probably be the easiest way to index your content.

No matter what technology you are using for your web application, Solr has [a lot of connectors.](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr)

Comment: I have cache memory requirement of 200 Mb .my table is  simple with 4 columns and i want to search against one column that has company name against it.However It has 2 million rows.The database search takes time of 4 seconds.I want to figure out a way to search that will work within 1 second.Will lucene be helpful here or will ehcache be useful here?

Comment: I don't get your question. If you need full-text search then Lucene may be a solution. AFAIK Ehcache doesn't have full-text capabilities.

Comment: I don't need full text search.I have four columns in my table for which  i want to make the search faster.Out of that searching is to be done on only 2 columns.

Comment: According to your last comment, you need to be able to query on prefixes. Then Lucene/Solr is probably a better fit.

Comment: Which is more preferable :-(1.)Lucene for accessing data. Or
(2.) Using a standalone cache like ehcache.